# Favourability of leaving groups in nucleophilic aromatic substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

It is known that the order of leaving group favourability of the halide ions changes when we go from nucleophilic substitution, in the form of $
\ce {S_N1}$ and $\ce {S_N2}$ reactions, to nucleophilic aromatic substitution reactions ($\ce {S_NAr}$). In the former, the primary consideration is the strength of the $\ce {C-X}$ bond since the rate-determining step would always involve $\ce {C-X}$ bond cleavage. Thus, the order starts with $\ce {I^-}$  as the most favourable and $\ce {F^-}$ as the least. However, in the latter, the primary consideration is the ability of the halogen atom to withdraw electron density from the carbon atom it is attached to. This is because the rate-determining step is the initial addition to form the meisenheimer intermediate, which does not involve $\ce {C-X}$ bond cleavage. Thus, the order starts with $\ce {F-}$ as the most favourable and $\ce {I^-}$ as the least.

Apart from analysing the favourability of the halides as leaving groups in $\ce {S_NAR}$ reactions, I hardly see this concept being used to analyse the favourability of other leaving groups in $\ce {S_NAr}$ reactions. How would conventionally "bad" nucleophiles, such as $\ce {CH3O^-}$ or $\ce {OH^-}$, fare in such reactions? Would they be as superior as leaving groups like $\ce {F^-}$ or $\ce {Cl^-}$ in $\ce {S_NAr}$ reactions?

Some information is provided in Carey & Sundberg (2007) on this:

> Groups other than halogen can serve as leaving groups. Alkoxy groups are very poor leaving groups in $\ce {S_N2}$ reactions but can act as leaving groups in aromatic substitution. The reason is the same as for the inverted order of reactivity for the halogens. The rate-determining step is the addition, and the alkoxide can be eliminated in the energetically favorable rearomatization.

**Reference**

Carey, F. A.; Sundberg, R. J. Advanced Organic Chemistry Part A. Structure and Mechanisms (5th ed.). Springer, **2007**.

Comment: That is a pretty good question. Do you have any example where alcoky groups act as leaving groups in SNAr?